# Deleting files on FAT32 USB changes the first cluster information

Tags: usb, flash-memory

i have made a file recovery software, which reads the FAT32 directory entry and identifies the first cluster of the file and attempts to recover the data, it is supposedly to be working fine however when i try on a fat32 usb disk the following happens.

The Cluster number assigned to a file when it is not deleted is different from the cluster number, immediately after it is deleted. I used Disk Investigator and Tune Up Undelete to verify this, none of them w.ere able to recover the file. It was the common problem that, usually upon deleting the file's name first character is changed to 0xE5 and rest remains intact, but this is changing it's cluster information too.

Any help?
Can you try with your FAT32 USB and tell me what is happening?

My OS is Windows Vista, Pen Drive is Single Partition FAT32.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps vista really is intentionally changing the first cluster field within the directory entry?  What is it actually changing it to?  You didn't post any examples with real numbers.  If it's overwriting that field with some number like 0 or 0xFFFFFFFF in every case, that's a pretty sure sign Vista is intentionally destroying this information so you can't find the file.  If it's changing that field, unnecessarily, to some other valid cluster number, well that's very strange.

Another thing you didn't mention is if the file's data is actually still physically on the disk in the cluster where it was originally located.  Seeing actual sector dumps of what is physically stored in the old locations and new location (assuming the new value is a cluster number which really exists) would be interesting.  If neither location has the actual file data, you could do a complete capture of all sectors and search.  Is the file's original data even still on the drive in any cluster/sector at all?

I know this isn't much of an answer, but with so little information (and not much inclination to actually install Vista and try this stuff), this is about all I can do.

Comment: Thanks paul, i shall update you tomorrow with the findings.. As far as i remember.. It wasn't 0 or 0xFFFFFFFF, it was another cluster number, which i noticed was being assigned to every file i delete. I didn't check what happens if i delete two files at the same time. Also the physical data was always there at the original location.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing the **USB [Wear Leveling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_levelling)** effect.

This post on [**Advice for Testing USB sticks and Data recovery tools**](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=19055.0) has more notes on this.

> Because of wear leveling (the controller switches data to different sectors to increase life expectancy of the memory chips on write operations) USB sticks cannot be easily handled by standard hard drive diagnostic utilities.

---

Update: Reference that contradicts my assumptions above.
There is a recent thesis on [The forensic potential of flash memory](http://simson.net/clips/students/09Sep_Regan.pdf) which
says that
wear-leveling works at the physical level and does not impact the 
logical level (software access).
<sub>Have not read this thesis yet... but, it seems to be good information for all interested in flash devices.</sub>

Comment: Dueto that explanation you quoted, the _controller_ on the stick would perform this action, though, meaning the block numbering the OS (Windows) sees would NOT change.
dlamblin's explanation is more likely the correct one here.

Comment: You are not seeing wear leveling because that happens at the physical level and not the logical level. See Thesis: Recovery of Deleted Data from Flash Memory Devices, James Regan, Naval Postgraduate School, Master's Thesis, 2009. http://simson.net/clips/students/09Sep_Regan.pdf

Comment: @simsong, hmmm. Thanks for posting your recent research as a reference. Had not found any clear data on the subject and was under the impression that wear-leveling would interfere with software based recovery. Will check your thesis.

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this question while googling the same issue. The question is old, but I hope my answer will help.

This problem has nothing to do with Flash memory issues. When a file is deleted from a FAT32 partition, its first cluster's high word is zeroed out, plain and simple (https://www.cnwrecovery.com/html/fat32.html).

It is thus impossible to straightforwardly recover deleted files (and directories) on FAT32, unlike FAT12/FAT16.

Answer (score 0):

To put it shortly: in flash memory, when a block is written to, a cluster of blocks around that block must first be erased, then re-written with the changes to the block taken into account. Therefore, writing to a block whose neighbor is marked as unallocated (though you actually want that data later) might be causing the unallocated block to be written as zeros. Alternatively, the old block might be marked unallocated, and a new block in an already blank cluster could be written to with the changes, and then the block changes would get noted somewhere.

This behavior is not OS specific but actually handled by the USB device itself. We would therefore need to know what kind of device you're using, unless what you are saying is that this happens on all your USB flash devices, which wasn't clear in your question.

The long version is much better explained by Anand Shimpi in his now famous [SSD Anthology](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3531) article (E.G. in the degradation chapter); there's even a [detailed follow up](http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3631) if you like that sort of thing.

Comment: This is incorrect. The USB controller hides these physical effects and presents a logical level that is indistinguishable from magnetic storage.   See Thesis: Recovery of Deleted Data from Flash Memory Devices, James Regan, Naval Postgraduate School, Master's Thesis, 2009. http://simson.net/clips/students/09Sep_Regan.pdf

Comment: @simsong Hey I don't mind being corrected, especially if I am wrong, but I can't actually read a fricking post-doc thesis on the subject to figure out which of my three sentences is wrong. Could you summarize a correction for me? Otherwise I won't learn anything. Personally I suspect I'm not wrong and you simply misunderstood what I said because I was summarizing a kind of detailed process in a couple of lines of text.

Comment: Your AnandTech reference is good. However, I wonder if the discussion on page 8 (http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3531&p=8) is about the firmware on the flash device (the physical layer) and the OS (logical view) does not see this detail. The performance impact nevertheless remain as Anand describes. Ok, have not read the thesis or the entire SSD discussion yet, that's on my reading list. But, I do think both these answers and references are good to retain here (+1 here too).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to compare the code that you have written to the "icat" and "fls" programs that are part of SleuthKit, the open source computer forensics toolkit. Using SleuthKit you can easily find the directory entries for deleted FAT32 files and then icat the inodes. You can find SleuthKit at http://sleuthkit.org/